# PHP - Google URL Shortener not working on Localhost

Tags: php, google-url-shortener

I'm using this [method](https://davidwalsh.name/google-url) to Google Shorten a Long URL via PHP on server side.

But it return me this error :

`"domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "ipRefererBlocked", "message": "The referrer null does not match does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."`

But I already set the Referrer to localhost & 127.0.0.1
[image]

[image]

I also enabled google shortener and check its quota
[image]

May I know what settings else I didn't configure or Google Shortener not working on http://localhost?

Comment: try adding `*.localhost/*` and `*.localhost` to the list of referrer

Comment: @SML , Already wait 5min+ after update `*.localhost/*` & `*.localhost`, Still facing the same error message..

Comment: not a proper answer to your question but if you remove all the referrer you have there, it will permit all traffic to go through.